# A question on interior of a set .

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let

- ${A_j},{\Delta _j} \in {\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}},(j = 0,1,2....m)$
- ${\rm{P(}}\lambda {\rm{) = }}{{\rm{A}}_m}{\lambda ^m} + .....{A_1}\lambda  + {A_0}$ is a matrix polynomial,  and $\lambda $ is a complex variable.
- ${P_\Delta }(\lambda ) = ({A_m} + {\Delta _m}){\lambda ^m} + ....... + ({A_1} + {\Delta _1}){\lambda ^1} + ({A_0} + {\Delta _0})$
- $\left\| {{.}} \right\| $ is any subordinate matrix norm.
- ${w_j} \ge 0,(j = 0,1....,m)$
- $D = \left\{ {{P_\Delta }(\lambda ):\left\| {{\Delta _j}} \right\| \le \ {w_j}} ,j=0,1,2,...,m\right\}$
- $Int( D)$ is interior of $D$.

Why does

$Int( D) = \{ {P_\Delta }(\lambda ):\left\| {{\Delta _j}} \right\| < \,{w_j}$,whenever $w_j>0$, and $\Delta_j=0$ whenever  $w_j=0$$\}$

Comment: If you take the usual topology on polynomials (i.e. the product topology on the coefficients), then the interior is empty whenever $w_j = 0$ for some $j$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - Let $\left\| {\sum\limits_j {{M_j}{\lambda ^j}} } \right\| = \mathop {\max }\limits_j \left\| {{M_j}} \right\|$.What about this norm?

Comment: Yes, that's the same idea.  The interior should be the empty set as long as $w_j = 0$ for some $j$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - In this case, why  interior should be the empty set as long as $w_j=0$ for some $j$.Please more guide.